# Backbone.js HTTP PUT requests fail with a 404 error when sent to a Pyramid/Cornice app

Tags: python, backbone.js, pyramid, cornice

I'm using Pyramid with [Cornice](http://cornice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to create an API for a Backbone.js application to consume. My current code is working perfectly for `GET` and `POST` requests, but it is returning 404 errors when it receives `PUT` requests. I believe that this is because Backbone sends them as `http://example.com/api/clients/ID`, where `ID` is the id number of the object in question.

My Cornice setup code is:

```
clients = Service(name='clients', path='/api/clients', description="Clients")

@clients.get()
def get_clients(request):
    ...

@clients.post()
def create_client(request):
    ...

@clients.put()
def update_client(request):
    ...
```

It seems that Cornice only registers the path `/api/clients` and not `/api/clients/{id}`. How can I make it match both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://cornice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html) gives an example of a service that has both an individual path (`/users/{id}`) and an object path (`/users`). Would this work for you ?

```
@resource(collection_path='/users', path='/users/{id}')
```

---

A quick glance at the [code for the `resource` decorator](https://github.com/mozilla-services/cornice/blob/master/cornice/resource.py) shows that it mainly creates two `Service` : one for the object and one for the collection. Your problem can probably be solved by adding another `Service` :

```
client = Service(name='client', path='/api/clients/{id}', description="Client")
```

Comment: Thanks, your second suggestion worked. I tried using @resource, and it worked fine for the GET and PUT calls, but simply refused to recognise the POST call (I tried it both as post() and collection_post() but it kept throwing 501s)